# Access denied to C:\program file\myapplicationfolder\

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to save an xml file to `C:\Program file\MyApplicationFolder\my.xml`, but I am receving an access denied error.

How can I save the file successfully?

Please help me! Here is my code

```
using(XmlWritter write=XmlWritter.Create(Application.StartUppath){write.WriteStartDocument();
            write.WriteStartElement("Setting");
            write.WriteElementString("Username", name);
            write.WriteElementString("Password", psw);
            write.WriteEndElement();
            write.WriteEndDocument();
```

Comment: We need to see your code and the error message to help

Comment: Does the user running your application have permissions to write to that folder?

Comment: don't save into that folder.  most likely it's protected by the system against modificatios

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Access denied to path in a Windows Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945549/c-sharp-access-denied-to-path-in-a-windows-application)

Answer (score 6):

**C:\Program Files** is a restricted folder.  Only administrators can modify the contents of this folder.

Use this code to generate a path:

```
FileName = Path.Combine( _
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), _
    "MyApplicationFolder\My.xml" _
)
```

This saves to a folder the user has access to:

> C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\MyApplicationFolder\My.xml

Answer (score 1):

Try saving to the per-user Application Data directory instead.