# How to make WIX create files to Program Files folder in the installation? I have "Access defined"

Tags: windows-7, installation, wix, access-denied

I am creating a WIX installer project. During one managed customized action, I need to create a file (other than the deployed files specified in the components of WIX) in the installation folder, which by default is the Program Files folder. I am experiencing the "Access denied" problem in Windows 7. After some searching, I found out that people say it is not advisable to create files into Program Files folder. Instead, try to create files into for example AppData folder. For example, see this link:
[C# Access denied to path in a Windows Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945549/c-sharp-access-denied-to-path-in-a-windows-application)

But my question is, the generated file is crucial to our SW, so it must reside in the installation folder. Isn't it the target of SW installation, I mean, to create file in most of the cases Program Files folder? Does it mean the only files should be added into installation folder, during the installation, are the deployed files (basically the targets of XCopy)?

My file can't be made deploy-able in the WIX, i.e, it can't be made ready before the installation. So what's the proper way or best practice to handle such situation: a file must be generated during the installation, into the installation folder. It is not some log file that I can put somewhere else. I tried to create a Permission element in WIX for the INSTALLADIR, although it seems to be against the rule mentioned in the link, but it still failed. Thanks!

UPDATE:

Based one MichaelUrman's commen, some more information. The generated file is needed after the SW is installed and necessary during normal launch of the SW. And I think it needs to be modified during normal use after the installation. And as I mentioned my a comment to @caveman_dick answer, my CA is actually in commit phase, I don't know whether there is any difference between it and normal deferred CA

Comment: Please clarify when this file needs to be created and/or modified. There's one answer if it only needs to be created or modified by the installation, and another if it has to be editable at arbitrary times after installation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the custom action to `Execute="deferred"`, that will run the command elevated and should give it the required permissions to create the file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have two further questions: 1) should I also specify Impersonate = 'no' ? Because I found out by default it is set to 'yes', which to my understanding means it will use my logon user's privileges, and normally doesn't have the permission to modify files in Program Files folder. 2) what if my CA is in commit phase (my Execute='commit')?

Comment: Yes to make any changes to the Program files directory you will have to mark it as Impersonate = 'no' too. If it is set to impersonate, you  will get permissions problems like you are having.

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to update that file from the main application, and I'm assuming your application does not require elevated privileges, you have three options.

1. The first is the worst: without a manifest, your executable's attempts to write to the Program Files folder will typically result in it being redirected to the Virtual Store (see [File Virtualization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb756960.aspx)). It sounds like this isn't happening in your case, so you can't use it.
2. The second option is to modify the application to store this in an appropriate location such as the ProgramData folder, or Common Documents, or (if appropriate) a per-user location under LocalAppData. This is typically the best approach, but has the highest development costs.
3. Finally the third option is to create the file and change its permissions (or in some cases to change the permissions on the folder containing the file), allowing limited users to modify this file. See LockPermissions or MsiLockPermissionsEx for the Windows Installer way to approach this. Change the permissions on as few files or folders, as restricted as possible, to keep the system as safe as possible if you go with this option.

Comment: Thanks Michael, that's really inspiring. I think I would go with 3rd option. Currently I am using elevated privileges for my custom action to create the file, it works fine but brings a small problem and we are seeking for the alternative to not to run the CA as system account. Let's say my generated file should be right under INSTALLDIR, I tried to give the logon user write permission to this directory using a Permission element in my WIX, but still I got the when running my CA without elevated privileges. Any thought on that?