# WriteAllBytes to an "in program" created directory Access to path Denied

Tags: c#, access-denied, directory-permissions

Hi made a little installer in C# with app.manifest parametter to AdministratorRequired to be able to edit the computer freely, but when I execute this code:

```
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(cheminInstall.Text);
File.WriteAllBytes(cheminInstall.Text, Properties.Resources.Sara);
```

Comment: what does `cheminInstall.Text` contains? is it file name? directory path? or full file path?

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945549/c-sharp-access-denied-to-path-in-a-windows-application)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please be aware that tags stand alone.  You can't combine tags to create new concepts.  Combining `access` and `denied` is not the same thing as the single tag `access-denied`.  Also, please be sure to read the helpful tag descriptions that appear in the tag list for tips on their use.

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing Directory with file. You can write to a file, and save it into a directory. But can't write directly into a directory.

```
cheminInstall.Text = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles)+"\\Storationer";
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(cheminInstall.Text);
File.WriteAllBytes(cheminInstall.Text+"\\YourFileName.txt", Properties.Resources.Sara);
```

Comment: Ow are you shure I can't directly write files from resources to directory, (i have alraydy did before but in My Documents and it worked).
So how can I write my resource file ???

Comment: @hugodecasta what does cheminInstall.Text contain?

Comment: It contains the path (chemin in french) to the programe files:
cheminInstall.Text = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles);

Comment: Oh ofcourse you can't create a folder that already exists @hugodecasta

Comment: No in fact the cheminInstall.text contains what is written on top +"/Storationer" (sorry to have forgotten)

Comment: +1 - as clearly `CreateDirectory` and than writing to the same location will fail. Note on your comment that "can't create folder that already exist" is true, but probably in different meaning: `Directory.CreateDirectory` will succeed for existing directory, but do nothing (check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s(v=vs.110).aspx))

Comment: O YES THANCKS YOU ANIKET FOR YOUR CODE ... I was so upset that i didn't see my BIIIIG error of the file/directory ... THANCK YOU VERY MUCH, And a great happy new year et bonne santé et meilleurs voeux as we say in France ;)

Comment: et bonne sante et meilleurs voeux :-) to you and your family

Answer (score 2):

Look at the code:

```
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(cheminInstall.Text);
File.WriteAllBytes(cheminInstall.Text, ...);
```

Well, you create a directory, and then try to write a file with the same name as the directory. That's not possible. You can write a file **in** a directory. You can overwrite an existing file with a new file. But you cannot write a file to a path that specifies a directory.

I don't know what you mean to do. But presumably you wish to create a directory, and write a file inside that directory. Which is going to require you to pass a path to WriteAllBytes that specifies an object within the directory that you create.

Comment: Yes i know i alrady answer the last second code was the good, thancks enought ^^

Comment: @hugo What do you mean, "Yes, I Know"? You asked a question. And we attempted to answer. Do you still need help?